# WebGL: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable (on chrome but not chromium)

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

I have webgl software only on chrome yet hardware accelerated on chromium on the same machine.

How can i figure out the problem? because if this happens for a lot of people then there is less incentive to use webgl in the first place.

Google Chrome:
[image: chrome]

Chromium:
[image: chromium]

Comment: Do you get hardware acceleration in [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/)?

Comment: @gman yes, just tested. canary 78 has hardware acceleration.

Comment: the software only screenshot above is from chrome 77

Comment: Well it sounds like either they fixed the issue in 78 or, you have some flags set? if you go to about:flags and click "Reset all to default" does it fix it?

Comment: Thank you so much,  resetting about:flags fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's also possible that nothing in `about:flags` will fix this

I have tried various tips like resetting all flags, or enabling the "Override software rendering list" option and they didn't work for me

It turns out there is another place to look, under `chrome://settings/` there is "Use hardware acceleration when available"

[image]

I remember now I had turned this off a few months ago as it was glitchy when using an external monitor via a Thunderbolt dock

Flipping it back on and using the laptop display only I now have nice smooth accelerated WebGL

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the comments, resetting all flags in about:flags fixed the issue.